# Prove $1/1^2 + 1/3^2 + \dotsb + 1/199^2 < 499/400$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that $\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{199^2}\frac{499}{400}$.

I thought of writing $1/3^2 < 1/(2 \cdot 3)$ and so on. Then we will alplificate with $2$ and put as comun factor $1/2$. We will apply the formula and then get $1 + 1/2 + 1/199$ but it still didn’t work.

Comment: Do you know how to compare your sum to the integral of the function $f(x)=1/x^2$?

Comment: Not really.....

Comment: But you can explain me

Comment: I suggest start with $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: @DanielV I guess it's overcomplicated for the given problem.

Comment: Yeahh....i didnt even learned this things

Comment: @openspace The bounds are so close, it seems like the easy answer to me.  You get $S(k) < S(\infty) = \pi^2/6 - 2^{-2} \pi^2/6$

Comment: How about $1/3^2\lt1/(2×4)$?

Comment: @DanielV can you try doing it by this method im not really sure where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on Empy2's comment, one can change the series in the following way

$$\sum_{k =1}^{100}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} < 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{(2k-2)(2k)}$$

In simpler words, we are replacing the square with the product of the predecessor and successor of the number.

Simplifying the sum on the right side of the inequality, we get the following sum

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$

This is a well known telescoping series. We will simplify it using the following partial fraction decomposition.

$$\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$$

Now we rewrite the sum as follows

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{4}(\sum_{k=2}^{100} \frac{1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{k}) $$

A simple change in indices will give us the following.

$$\frac{1}{4}(\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{k}) = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \frac{1}{100}) \\  = \frac{99}{400}$$

To explain what I did there, we had to remove the first term from the first series and  the last term from the latter one, hence the visible terms were left out. The rest of the series were the same hence were cancelled out. Now we finish

$$\sum_{k =1}^{100}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} < 1 + \frac{99}{400} = \frac{499}{400}$$

QED.